# Sencha Touch 2.1. ItemId is not working?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2.1

try create form login in Sencha Touch 2.1

```js
...
xtype: 'fieldset',
title: 'My Login',
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'emailfield',
        placeHolder: 'Username',
        itemId: 'userNameTextField',
        name: 'userNameTextField',
        required: true
    },
    {
        xtype: 'passwordfield',
        placeHolder: 'Password',
        itemId: 'passwordTextField',
        name: 'passwordTextField',
        required: true
    }
]
...
```

but in Chrome console

```html
<input id="ext-element-14" class="x-input-el x-form-field x-input-email" type="email" autocapitalize="off" placeholder="Username" name="userNameTextField">
```

why ItemId is not working?

Comment: Try adding `id` instead of `itemId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per

http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?196697-itemId-alone-not-working-for-ref-selectors&p=783360&viewfull=1#post783360 ,

Ext.ComponentQuery can only resolve a component using itemId if a parent component is referenced in the query so you are better off using `id` because I don't think you application would have many login panels and you can easily access these fields like:

```
var pwd = Ext.getCmp('passwordTextField');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call itemid in Sencha Touch by using : "#itemID"

```
var field = frmLogin.query("#userNameTextField")[0];
```

Hope can help you have same problem.!